# Setting a value within a nested function

Tags: go, nested-function

Been given this golang code, feel free critique is hard as my golang is rusty. Basic refresh token flow, however we are wrapping the functions in a TX function to allow rollback should something go wrong in the refresh flow.

We need to return the `newToken` value however it only hold the value we need during the `refresh` function when it return to refreshToken depending on if I pass it an object or pointer is returns new empty token or nil respectively.

```
package service

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "errors"
    "strings"

    "github.com/api-oauth/pkg/models"
    "github.com/api-oauth/pkg/repository"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
)

const minParts = 2

type OAuthAPI interface {
    Exchange(context.Context, string) (*oauth2.Token, error)
    Refresh(context.Context, string) (*oauth2.Token, error)
}

type Service struct {
    repo     repository.RepoInterface
    oauthAPI OAuthAPI
}

func New(api OAuthAPI, repo repository.RepoInterface) *Service {
    return &Service{repo: repo, oauthAPI: api}
}

var (
    ErrNoRefreshTokenFound = errors.New("no refresh token found")
    errNoScopesReturn      = errors.New("no scopes returned")
    errNoProfileFound      = errors.New("no profile found")
)

func (s *Service) RefreshToken(ctx context.Context, clientID string, userID int64) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
    var newToken *oauth2.Token

    err := s.repo.InTx(s.refresh(ctx, clientID, userID, newToken))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return newToken, nil
}

func (s *Service) refresh(ctx context.Context, clientID string, userID int64, newToken *oauth2.Token) func(repo repository.Auth) error {
    return func(repo repository.Auth) error {
        oldToken, err := repo.GetToken(ctx, userID, clientID)
        if err != nil && err != sql.ErrNoRows {
            return err
        }

        if oldToken == nil {
            return ErrNoRefreshTokenFound
        }

        newToken, err = s.oauthAPI.Refresh(ctx, oldToken.Refresh)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        rec := models.TokenRecord{
            UserID:    userID,
            ClientID:  clientID,
            ProfileID: oldToken.ProfileID,
            Access:    newToken.AccessToken,
            Refresh:   newToken.RefreshToken,
            Expiry:    newToken.Expiry,
        }

        err = repo.UpdateToken(ctx, &rec)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Trying to have `RefreshToken` return the updated token information

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/3G7BI3Ixbiw or https://go.dev/play/p/bgkcoKbEhYp

Comment: Gave the first one a shot gave me some error:

{"errorMessage":"runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference","errorType":"errorString","stackTrace":[{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.28.0/lambda/errors.go","line":39,"label":"lambdaPanicResponse"},{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.28.0/lambda/function.go","line":36,"label":"(*Function).Invoke.func1"},

Comment: As far as `newToken` is concerned in the first code example in the first comment, there is not issue and by itself will not cause the error you cite. If you want more concrete help you need to show the full stacktrace and the file:line which the stacktrace points out as the cause of the issue. Also, do not include that info in a comment please, instead update your question with the additional details.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/bgkcoKbEhYp - this however did work and much appreciated, could you give me a bit of a breakdown of why it did, I see you are using a pointer of a pointer and passing it that memory ref to the refresh func. If you would like to post your code and a breakdown as an answer it would help me and many others (I assume)

Comment: At the bottom of the `refresh` method you can see the statement `*newTokenPtr = newToken`, this updates the memory to which `&newToken`, passed to `refresh`, points to, which is the address of `newToken` variable in the `RefreshToken` method.

Comment: BurakSerdar's answer is essentially the same approach. You may as well accept it if you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass address of `newToken`:

```
func (s *Service) RefreshToken(ctx context.Context, clientID string, userID int64) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
    var newToken *oauth2.Token

    err := s.repo.InTx(s.refresh(ctx, clientID, userID, &newToken))
    ...
```

And, change the `refresh` function to:

```
func (s *Service) refresh(ctx context.Context, clientID string, userID int64, newToken **oauth2.Token) func(repo repository.Auth) error {
  ...
  *newToken, err=...
```